# PHP select the dates of a custom week range

Tags: php

PHP 7.1.7

There's a work function I'm dealing with that has a custom "week" (where a "week" for this function is Saturday through Friday).

For any given day of the week, how could I set two variables to contain the start of the custom defined week (Saturday) and the end of the custom defined week (Friday).

So, if I had a date of 8-11-17, I would need to come up with a a start date variable holding 8-05-17 and an end date variable holding 8-11-17.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understood the question correct but is this what you are looking for?
It uses strtotime() to find previous saturday from input. Then next friday from that saturday.

```
$Input = "08/12/2017";
if(date("l", strtotime($Input)) == "Saturday"){
    $Saturday = strtotime($Input);
}else{
    $Saturday = strtotime($Input . " previous saturday");
}
$Friday =  strtotime(date("m/d/Y", $Saturday) . " next friday");

echo date("m/d/Y", $Saturday) . " to " . date("m/d/Y", $Friday);
```

https://3v4l.org/l4g8D

EDIT; I just noticed if the Input is a saturday my code choosed the wrong dates. Corrected.

Comment: that code seems to work perfectly with a few test dates I tried.  Thank you very much!

Comment: @Reno Thank you! I wasn't sure how to handle if input is a Saturday, but I made it count that Saturday as the start day then.

Answer (score 2):

you could use date('w') to determine the day of week for given date.
If the number found is less than 6, move that number + 1 backwards. That's your starting date. End date will be 7 days later:

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('08-11-2017');
$daynumber = $date->format('w');

if($daynumber < 6) {
  $tomove = $daynumber + 1;
  $date->modify('-' . $tomove.'day');
}
$startdate = $date;

$enddate = clone $date;
$enddate->modify('+7day');

echo $startdate->format('d-m-y');
echo $enddate->format('d-m-y');
?>
```

edit

forgot the word "day" in modify

Comment: What does this code do? It seems to me both startdate and enddate is the same as the input whatever you input. https://3v4l.org/0vWhA

Comment: @Andreas indeed. I forgot the word Day in the modify part

Comment: Right now the output is: 04-11-17, 11-11-17  (should be 08-05 to 08-11).  I'm .  I'm a little lost on how to fix the code sorry.

Comment: As I read it: 4-11 is the 4th day of November. I get the idea you think otherwise?

Comment: and November 4th is the Saturday before Wednesday the 8th of November. Seems right to me

Comment: I believe his format is "m-d-Y" which is an incorrect date form for php. m/d/Y is valid though.

Comment: for Europe d-m-Y is normal format. when using // in the date I would think of the "american" backwards format

Comment: when using a obscure format like a 2digit year, one could better use DateTime::createFromFormat